# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud' has no attribute 'storage'

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run a simple beam script on GCP Dataflow in order to apply a scikit-learn model to some data. The data needs to be processed before and after the model is applied. That is what the textExtraction and translationDictionary are.  I keep getting the error `AttributeError: module 'google.cloud' has no attribute 'storage'` (full stack trace below).  As you can see, I tried running in a new virtual environment with new installations.  Any idea how to fix?

I also have my script given below.

predict_DF_class.py

```
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
from google.cloud import storage
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import parse_table_schema_from_json
import pandas as pd
import pickle as pkl
import json
import joblib

query = """
    SELECT index, product_title
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    LIMIT 1000
"""

class ApplyDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        self._model = None
        self._textExtraction = None
        self._translationDictionary = None
        self._storage = storage
        self._pkl = pkl
        self._pd = pd
        self._joblib = joblib

    def process(self, element):
        if self._model is None:
            bucket = self._storage.Client().get_bucket(
                'marketing-analytics-data')
            blob = bucket.get_blob('model.joblib')
            self._model = self._joblib.load(blob.download_as_string())
        if self._textExtraction is None:
            bucket = self._storage.Client().get_bucket(
                'marketing-analytics-data')
            blob = bucket.get_blob('tfidfit')
            self._textExtraction = self._pkl.loads(blob.download_as_string())
        if self._translationDictionary is None:
            bucket = self._storage.Client().get_bucket(
                'marketing-analytics-data')
            blob = bucket.get_blob('id_to_category')
            self._translationDictionary = self._pkl.loads(blob.download_as_string())

        new_x = self._pd.DataFrame.from_dict(element,
                                             orient="index").transpose().fillna(0)
        course = self._translationDictionary[self._model.predict(self._text_extraction.transform(new_x.iloc[:, 1:]).toarray()).tolist()[0]]
        return [{'guid': element['index'], 'product_title':element['product_title'], 'course_id': course}]

schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps({'fields':
            [ { 'name': 'index', 'type': 'INTEGER'},
              { 'name': 'product_title', 'type': 'STRING'},
              { 'name': 'course_id', 'type': 'STRING'} ]}))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(None)
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

# define the pipeline steps
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
data = p | 'Read from BigQuery' >> beam.io.Read(
       beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True))
scored = data | 'Apply Model' >> beam.ParDo(ApplyDoFn())
scored | 'Save to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
                'output_table', 'dataset', 'project', schema = schema,
   create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))

# run the pipeline
result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

error:

```
(env) (base) HOBNJML-C40PLVD:predictions uswygst$ python predict_DF_class.py   --runner DataflowRunner   --project $PROJECT    -requirements_file "requirements.txt"   --temp_location gs://marketing-analytics-data/template/
predict_DF_class.py:53: BeamDeprecationWarning: parse_table_schema_from_json is deprecated since 2.11.0. Use bigquery_tools.parse_table_schema_from_json instead.
  { 'name': 'courseid', 'type': 'STRING'} ]}))
/Users/uswygst/Documents/Company/Projects/AAA/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py:1479: BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to <pipeline>.options will not be supported
  experiments = p.options.view_as(DebugOptions).experiments or []
/Users/uswygst/Documents/Company/Projects/AAA/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/ptransform_overrides.py:315: BeamDeprecationWarning: BigQuerySink is deprecated since 2.11.0. Use WriteToBigQuery instead.
  kms_key=self.kms_key))
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.7 interpreter.
WARNING:apache_beam.options.pipeline_options:Discarding unparseable args: ['-requirements_file', 'requirements.txt']
WARNING:apache_beam.options.pipeline_options:Discarding unparseable args: ['-requirements_file', 'requirements.txt']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict_DF_class.py", line 71, in <module>
    result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/Users/uswygst/Documents/Company/Projects/AAA/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1629, in wait_until_finish
    self)
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 283, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 827, in _import_module
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud' has no attribute 'storage'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 638, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute
    op.start()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 662, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 664, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 665, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 284, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 290, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.start
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 611, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.setup
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 616, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 287, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 827, in _import_module
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud' has no attribute 'storage'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dataflow isn't reading requirements.txt:

> WARNING:apache_beam.options.pipeline_options:Discarding unparseable args: ['-requirements_file', 'requirements.txt']

Note that you need to use double hyphens for the `requirements_file` flag.

I.E. `-requirements_file "requirements.txt"` -> `--requirements_file requirements.txt`